# How to call html file from method of visual c# in bot framework.?

Tags: c#

I create GET method in TestController.js and call that JS file in Test.html file. I want to call that Test.html file from ResumeGetEmail() method in AnnualPlanDialog.cs class. How to do it. This is related with bot framework. I want to get data from database into bot via calling web API.
[AnnualPlanDialog.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6cFQ.png)[Test.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6fiz.png)[TestController.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWaeD.png)

```js
$http({ method: 'GET', url: "/api/TestAPI", params: { TenantId: 'TT', CompanyId: 'TC1' } }).
                      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          $scope.Company = data;
                      }).
                      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          console.log(data);
                      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../JsControllers/ResQ/TestController.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>    
    <h1>Company Id {{Company.CompanyId}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
public virtual async Task ResumeGetEmail(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> UserEmail)
    {
        string response = await UserEmail;
        phone = response;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            await context.PostAsync(String.Format("Hello {0} ,Now you know data of " + plandetails + " from database.Thank you. Access Name = {0} Email = {1} {2} .", name, email, phone));
            await context.PostAsync("");

        }
        //context.Done(this);
    }
```

Comment: Post your code here with your question. Not screenshots. Also be specific about which part of code you need help with

Answer (score 0):

You need to use routeProvider from the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) dependency.

Create a main controller with routing implemented:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngRoute"]).
      config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          //Home page
          $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'Html/login.html',
              controller: 'myController'
          });
          //Test page
          $routeProvider.
          when('/test', {
              templateUrl: 'Html/test.html',
              controller: 'myController'
          });
    });
```

and use it like this:

```
http({ method: 'GET', url: "/api/TestAPI", params: { TenantId: 'TT', CompanyId: 'TC1' } }).
                      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          $scope.Company = data;
                          $location.path("/test");
                      }).
                      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          console.log(data);
                      });
```

Since this is angular, it is better not to involve client-side-code in server-side-code.

Get your response from the server and transfer to the desired page.

If you use angular, max it's possibilities to the limits.

Comment: I not use the emulator. Bot published in Azure. And  also I coded in .Net. Therefore, Is it need the ngRoute.?

Comment: Thank you @BarrJ. Is it need the ngRoute.?

Comment: No problems. yes, ngRoute dependency.